# EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when using an NSURLSession NSURLSessionDownloadTask on some hardware in iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask, ios-9-beta3

**UPDATE**

Works in iOS9 Beta 5

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

Executing this line of code causes an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error to happen shortly after in some library code on a non-main thread before the completion handler is called.

```
[[[NSURLSession sharedSession]  downloadTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png"]
                                  completionHandler:^(NSURL *location,
                                                      NSURLResponse *response,
                                                      NSError *error) {
                                      NSLog(@"At Download Completion Handler");   
                                  }] resume];
```

It happens on my iPad model A1403 on iOS 9 Beta 3 and 4, but not on iOS8.1, and works fine on my iPad model A1566 on both iOS 9 and iOS 8.4.

I've logged a bug with Apple.

Is anyone else having this issue? Does anyone see a workaround?

Tests:

1. iOS 8.1 - device A1566 - **working**
2. iOS 8.4 - device A1403 - **working**
3. iOS 9 beta 4 - simulator - **working**
4. iOS 9 beta 4 - device A1566 - **working**
5. iOS 9 beta 3 - device A1403 - **NOT WORKING**
6. iOS 9 beta 4 - device A1403 - **NOT WORKING**

Testing by Tander:

1. iOS 8.3 - device - **working**
2. iOS 9 beta 0 - simulator - **working**
3. iOS 9 beta 4 - device - **working**

So the problem is really only occurring on device A1403 with iOS 9...

Answer (score 1):

So I have tested this bit of code for you on the following versions of iOS: `8,3` (device) `9.0` (Simulator) and `9.4` (Device) - the `completionHandler` always executes and the log is printed out on all test devices. Not a bug it would seem. Are you testing on an actual device(s) ?

Comment: Interesting. I have two devices, an iPad 3rd gen (A1403) running IOS 9 beta 4, and an iPad Air 2 (A1555) running IOS 8.1. I have the problem only on the iPad 3rd gen. I just tested on the simulator and it works on IOS 9 beta 4. So it seems like it is hardware related?

Comment: Very possible its hardware related. Maybe do a soft reset on the device. I'll run it on an iPad and see what the results are and update here once I have done that. Interested to see if its not device related. Will get back to you tomorrow.

Comment: Soft reset did not help. BUT, I downgraded to iOS 8.4 on the device where I was having trouble (A1403), and it __does__ work. So it seems like  A1403 + iOS 9 is the problem...

Comment: I upgraded my A1566 iPad to iOS 9 beta 4, and it works. So really the only time it does not work is A1403 iPad + iOS 9, so definitely hardware specific.

Comment: So I tested it on my iPad 2 (A1396) iOS9.4 and my iPhone 5s (A1530) 9,4 Beta and a test device iPhone 6 (A1549) iOS 8.3. and all works just fine. So it is hardware related. I wonder if it is specific to your device though? I wish I had an A1403 iPad to try out...

Comment: Thanks for the extensive testing. It would be really nice to have another A1403 to test this on.

Comment: I might have access to one on Monday. If I do, I'll test and get back to you. Interested to see if its related to just your device or all A1403's.

Comment: Awesome. That would be great to know.

Comment: I've tested on another A1403, and I can reproduce the bug. @Tander, were you able to get your hands on an A1403?

Comment: @user2771609 - I only have an iPad Mini 2 to test against. Though it seems this bug is related to A1403 devices. If you'd like I'll test against the iPad Mini 2 ?

Comment: If you can't get your hand on an A1403, then don't worry about it. It seems like an A1403 + iOS 9 bug. I'll try to work with Apple to get them to fix it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user2771609 Interestingly enough I have a bug too. on iPad 2 + iOS9 B4 my app crashes - not in my own code either. Same iPad + iOS8 no issues. On iPad Mini 2  + iOS9 no problems. Would be interesting to see what Apple find. Keep us updated

Comment: Ha! What is the model number of your iPad 2?

Comment: Its a A1396 - 3G + WiFi